# Does nginx buffer its error logs?

Tags: web, nginx

We're looking to watch nginx error logs for modifications but having some difficultly accounting for edge cases such as file truncations, etc.

It would be helpful to know if nginx writes its error log files on the fly or if it buffers writes to error logs. Buffering wouldnt make a lot of sense for error logs but could still be the case to ensure high performance in nginx.

We know that nginx buffers access log writes but cant currently find evidence that it does the same for error logs.

Comment: Error log should not be buffered.  One may edit conf and then reload nginx.  If there is a mistake, a message should now show up in the error log.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, error log writes aren't buffered.

Comment: Even in commercial version? O_o

Comment: @poige, yes, even in commercial version. Error logs are designed to be simple and reliable, to make sure errors will be logged even in critical cases, e.g., when nginx is unable to allocate memory. OS write caching is usually enough to handle logged errors. If it's not in your case, consider tuning logging level.